# @import media queries css issue

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am preparing my first responsive web layout.

I have prepared two css one is for normal mode and other one is for mobile mode.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" 
href="css/mobile.css" />
</head>
```

Desktop mode (CSS)

```css
#face
{
background-image: url(../images/Face.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height:155px;
}
```

mobile mode (CSS)

```css
#face
{
display:none;
}
```

But when decrease my browser window to mobile mode still #face this is displaying.

Kindly suggest me what I am doing wrong

Thanks in advance.

M

Comment: Where's your `@import` statement?

Comment: Hi I am not getting could you please explain me more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max-device-width` measures the width of the screen, not the width of the browser.
Change that to `max-width`.

Comment: I did it but still i am not getting actual output

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #face
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

try this

Or you can use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="mobile.css" />
```